# How to show the image which is picked with react native image picker?

Tags: react-native

**Problem:**

I have created an image and video picker with react-native-image-picker. This is how my code looks like.

```
import React, {useState, createRef} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
} from 'react-native';
import AppText from '_components/appText';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import {strings} from '_translations/i18n';
import styles from './newpatientassetmentstyle';
import PlayerControls from '_components/playerControls';
import Video from 'react-native-video';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';

const showControls = (state, setState) => {
  state.showControls
    ? setState({...state, showControls: false})
    : setState({...state, showControls: true});
};

const handlePlayPause = (state, setState) => {
  if (state.play) {
    setState({...state, play: false, showControls: true});
    return;
  }

  setState({...state, play: true});
  setTimeout(() => setState((s) => ({...s, showControls: false})), 2000);
};

function onLoadEnd(data, state, setState) {
  setState({
    ...state,
    duration: data.duration,
    currentTime: data.currentTime,
  });
}

function onProgress(data, state, setState) {
  setState({
    ...state,
    currentTime: data.currentTime,
  });
}

const onEnd = (state, setState, player) => {
  setState({
    ...state,
    showControls: false,
    play: false,
    currentTime: 0,
    duration: 0,
  });
  player.current.seek(0);
};

const openPicker = async (type, setFileObject) => {
  let options;
  if (type === 4) {
    options = {
      title: 'Upload Image',
      quality: 1,
      mediaType: 'photo',
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
        path: 'images',
      },
    };
  } else if (type === 5) {
    options = {
      title: 'Upload Video',
      videoQuality: 'high',
      mediaType: 'video',
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
        path: 'images',
      },
    };
  }

  ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
    if (response.didCancel) {
      console.log('User cancelled image picker');
    } else if (response.error) {
      console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
    } else if (response.customButton) {
      console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
    } else {
      setFileObject(response);
    }
  });
};

const DocumentUpload = (props) => {
  const {type} = props;
  const [fileObject, setFileObject] = useState(null);
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    fullscreen: false,
    play: false,
    currentTime: 0,
    duration: 0,
    showControls: true,
  });

  const player = createRef();
  return (
    <View>
      {type === 5 && (
        <View style={styles.videoContainer}>
          <View style={styles.videoInnerContainer}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback
              onPress={() => showControls(state, setState)}>
              <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <Video
                  source={{
                    uri: fileObject.uri,
                  }}
                  controls={false}
                  style={styles.backgroundVideo}
                  ref={player}
                  resizeMode={'contain'}
                  paused={!state.play}
                  onEnd={() => onEnd(state, setState, player)}
                  onLoad={(data) => onLoadEnd(data, state, setState)}
                  onProgress={(data) => onProgress(data, state, setState)}
                />
                {state.showControls && (
                  <View style={styles.controlsOverlay}>
                    <PlayerControls
                      play={state.play}
                      playVideo={handlePlayPause}
                      state={state}
                      setState={setState}
                      pauseVideo={handlePlayPause}
                    />
                  </View>
                )}
              </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          </View>
        </View>
      )}
      {fileObject
        ? console.log(`data:${fileObject.type},${fileObject.data}`, 'fileOb')
        : null}
      {type === 4 && fileObject && (
        <View>
          <Image
            source={{uri: 'data:' + fileObject.type + ',' + fileObject.data}}
          />
        </View>
      )}
      {!fileObject ? (
        <>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => openPicker(type, setFileObject)}>
            <Image
              source={require('_assets/img/cmerap.png')}
              resizeMode="center"
              style={styles.camPImage}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <AppText styles={styles.camPText}>
            {strings('assetsment.capture')}
          </AppText>
        </>
      ) : (
        <View style={styles.videoBottomText}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => openPicker(type, setFileObject)}>
            <View style={styles.updateAgainContainer}>
              <Icon name="reload1" style={styles.reloadIcon} />
              <AppText styles={styles.reloadText}>
                {strings('assetsment.reload')}
              </AppText>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default DocumentUpload;
```

But when I try to show the picked image in the view but it is showing nothing in there. I tried a lot to find out what is wrong with this but I was unable to do so. Can someone help me to find out a solution to this problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the image selected you'll have a response object, in which you'll have the uri for the image chosen (you can console.log the response object to make sure what the key for the uri is). Once you have this object with the response, use its uri to set a state and make sure you use that state in your image tag, like this: `source={{ uri: imageUriFromState }}`

Answer (score 0):

One needs to set the height and weight for an image if it is not a static resource.